# How to get and set a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, syntax, jcombobox

What I have attached below is a copy/paste of my attempt to get and set a series of JComboBox's. hName and hAddress are dealing with a JTextField, so those are working fine, but for some reason I can get from my combo box's, but I can't set to them and including a call to initialiseDatabase() will cause the program to fail.

infoHolder is a resultset and dbstatement is a statement. The database is connecting fine, and the table inside of it is prepared and accessible, it's just the setting of the combobox's that's the issue.

Any help appreciated, and apologies if I'm missing something fundamental in the code below above.

```
 public void initialiseDatabase()
   {
    try
    {
        infoHolder = dBStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM House");
        infoHolder.next();

        hName = infoHolder.getString("Name");
        hAddress = infoHolder.getString("Address");
        numRooms = infoHolder.getInt("numRooms");
        Type = infoHolder.getString("Type");
        charge = infoHolder.getString("roomCharge");
        Access = infoHolder.getString("dAccess");
        Info = infoHolder.getString("oInfo");

        houseText.setText(" " +hName);
        addressText.setText(" " +hAddress);
        roomNumber.setSelectedItem(" " +numRooms);
        roomType.setSelectedItem(" " +Type);
        chargeRoom.setSelectedItem(" " +charge);
        access.setSelectedItem(" " +Access);
        oInfo.setText(" " +Info);

        current2 = 1;
        infoHolder.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e8) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Database failed to initialise!", "Message Dialog", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);;}
   }
```

Comment: use DefaultComboBoxModel, should be initialized as local variable before JDBC is called, inside JDBC code block to add a new Item to variable (representing a model)

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you mean? Thank you for the response, but how do I implement the DefaultComboBoxModel?

Comment: @user3822332 Do a google search for "How to use combobox"

Comment: @MadProgrammer it didn't cover what I needed.

Comment: If [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) don't cover what you need then I don't know how you expect us to add to it...